# Is there text "search and navigate" ability in WebStorm exists?

Tags: ide, webstorm

While learning AngularJS on egghead.io I've noticed some cool magic in WebStorm's editor window. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Unknown cool magic in WebStorm]

The cool thing is ability not only to search in place of editing, but navigate between occurrences in direct manner using map of letters. So there is no need to use "Go to next/Go to prev", all is needed is just to hit a single button to move cursor into known and required position.

The question is: is it some built-in functionality I don't about or just a plugin for that (unknown also)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's AceJump plugin (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yK8eM50DsAY, https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086?pr=idea). it's quite old unfortunately, not sure if it's compatible with most recent WebStorm versions

Comment: Thank you so much! Just for your knowing: this plugin works fine with PyCharm build 143.869